# Border for one column in Latex

Tags: tables

I am new to latex and I have trouble to find out what is going on in `table` environment.
I have a table and want to separate every 3 column with each other to look like this:
[image]

But my tex is like below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{booktabs ,float}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccclllllllll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{i}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Z\_i}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{U\_i}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{i}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Z\_i}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{U\_i}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{i}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Z\_i}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{U\_i}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{i}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Z\_i}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{U\_i}} \\ \hline
0                                & 7                                  & -                                  & 5                               & 10                                 & 0.652                              & 10                              & 9                                  & 0.563                              & 15                              & 4                                  & 0.250                              \\
1                                & 6                                  & 0.375                              & 6                               & 5                                  & 0.313                              & 11                              & 0                                  & 0.000                              & 16                              & 7                                  & 0.438                              \\
2                                & 1                                  & 0.063                              & 7                               & 12                                 & 0.750                              & 12                              & 3                                  & 0.188                              & 17                              & 6                                  & 0.375                              \\
3                                & 8                                  & 0.500                              & 8                               & 15                                 & 0.938                              & 13                              & 2                                  & 0.125                              & 18                              & 1                                  & 0.063                              \\
4                                & 11                                 & 0.688                              & 9                               & 14                                 & 0.875                              & 14                              & 13                                 & 0.813                              & 19                              & 8                                  & 0.500                             
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{ccc|ccc|ccc|ccc}` should fix this, if you at the same time remove all `\multicolumn` commands.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing all the occurences of `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}` in combination with using `\begin{tabular}{ccc|ccc|ccc|ccc}` should result in an output closer to the expected one. Personally, I recommend to not use vertical lines in a table. Instead you could use horizontal white space in combination with interrupted horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package in order to create a visual separation between teh 4 blocks in your table. For an improved alignment of numbers in your table, you may also want to consider using `S` type columns from `siunitx`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{booktabs ,float}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc|ccc|ccc|ccc}
\hline
$i$ & $Z_i$  & $U_i$ 
& $i$ & $Z_i$  & $U_i$ 
& $i$ & $Z_i$  & $U_i$ 
& $i$ & $Z_i$  & $U_i$  \\ \hline
0                                & 7                                  & -                                  & 5                               & 10                                 & 0.652                              & 10                              & 9                                  & 0.563                              & 15                              & 4                                  & 0.250                              \\
1                                & 6                                  & 0.375                              & 6                               & 5                                  & 0.313                              & 11                              & 0                                  & 0.000                              & 16                              & 7                                  & 0.438                              \\
2                                & 1                                  & 0.063                              & 7                               & 12                                 & 0.750                              & 12                              & 3                                  & 0.188                              & 17                              & 6                                  & 0.375                              \\
3                                & 8                                  & 0.500                              & 8                               & 15                                 & 0.938                              & 13                              & 2                                  & 0.125                              & 18                              & 1                                  & 0.063                              \\
4                                & 11                                 & 0.688                              & 9                               & 14                                 & 0.875                              & 14                              & 13                                 & 0.813                              & 19                              & 8                                  & 0.500                             
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ccc@{\qquad}ccc@{\qquad}ccc@{\qquad}ccc}
\toprule
$i$ & $Z_i$  & $U_i$ 
& $i$ & $Z_i$  & $U_i$ 
& $i$ & $Z_i$  & $U_i$ 
& $i$ & $Z_i$  & $U_i$  \\ 
\cmidrule(r{2em}){1-3} \cmidrule(r{2em}){4-6} \cmidrule(r{2em}){7-9} \cmidrule{10-12}
0 & 7   & --       & 5  & 10  & 0.652   & 10   & 9   & 0.563  & 15  & 4   & 0.250     \\
1 & 6   & 0.375    & 6  & 5   & 0.313   & 11   & 0   & 0.000  & 16  & 7   & 0.438     \\
2 & 1   & 0.063    & 7  & 12  & 0.750   & 12   & 3   & 0.188  & 17  & 6   & 0.375     \\
3 & 8   & 0.500    & 8  & 15  & 0.938   & 13   & 2   & 0.125  & 18  & 1   & 0.063     \\
4 & 11  & 0.688    & 9  & 14  & 0.875   & 14   & 13  & 0.813  & 19  & 8   & 0.500     \\  
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you get rid of the `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` wrappers, employ an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, and replace all instances of `\textbf` with `\bm`. I would also align the numbers in the "Z" columns on their (implicit) decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,bm}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional: Times Roman text and math fonts
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\[
\begin{array}{@{} *{3}{c S[table-format=2.0] c|} ccc @{}}
\hline
\bm{i} & {\bm{Z}_i} & \bm{U}_{\!i} & \bm{i} & {\bm{Z}_i} & \bm{U}_{\!i} & 
\bm{i} & {\bm{Z}_i} & \bm{U}_{\!i} & \bm{i} & {\bm{Z}_i} & \bm{U}_{\!i} \\ 
\hline
0  & 7 & \textup{--} & 5 & 10 & 0.652& 10& 9  & 0.563& 15& 4 & 0.250\\
1  & 6   & 0.375& 6 & 5   & 0.313& 11& 0   & 0.000& 16& 7   & 0.438\\
2  & 1   & 0.063& 7 & 12  & 0.750& 12& 3   & 0.188& 17& 6   & 0.375\\
3  & 8   & 0.500& 8 & 15  & 0.938& 13& 2   & 0.125& 18& 1   & 0.063\\
4  & 11  & 0.688& 9 & 14  & 0.875& 14& 13  & 0.813& 19& 8   & 0.500\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```